# Get Value of selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to copy the value of selected cell (ex. 2020/07/29) which is in date format and it will return only the year and month (2020/07). could anyone help me? thank you in advance

Comment: `Format(ActiveCell.Value, "yyyy/mm")`.

Comment: I displayed it through a variable selectedCell as Date (selectedCell = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "yyyy/mm") and it still displayed the day @BigBen

Comment: No repro........

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
Dim FileName As String

FileName = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "yy mmm")
Debug.Print FileName
```